# How to send query params to Header component that allways appears in _app? Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this code in _app.

```
<Header />
<Component {...pageProps} />
```

I want to send the Header component query param of the current selected tab.
So if someone navigates to 'http:domain.com/hello' i will get the hello as a query param inside the Header.

I know you can achieve that in create-react-app with react-router-dom like this:

```
<Route path="/:currentTab?" component={Header} />
```

How can i achieve that in Nextjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the useRouter at the Header Component
something along like

import { useRouter } from "next/router";

```
const Header = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return <h1> HI ! {router.pathname} </h1>;
};

export default Header;
```

Ofcourse  your pathname will include the `/` for example a site `/hello` url will show

`Hi /hello`

But you can start working out on that details as you move forward with your needs

You can see my sample fiddle here : https://codesandbox.io/s/2-route-inspection-in-custom-app-forked-828gu?file=/components/SiteLayout.js

**Another one**
Which kinda depends on how you structure your routing pages (reason why I haven't add as a example as because this were subjective to your structure) is for example adding a

[greet].js at your top level pages folder and accessing it the similar way
we do at react-router-dom

```
  const { greet } = router.query;
  return <h1> HI ! {greet} </h1>;
```

But because we don't know the structure at your app and the domain is top level. Its upto you if this case is viable

See the fiddle here: https://codesandbox.io/s/2-route-inspection-in-custom-app-forked-tnybv?file=/components/Header.js:95-162

Comment: I saw this approach, but i also have nested routes in the header (drop down to the tabs in the header), like '/hello/world' and i need to be able to extract the tab and the subTab, and i dont want to mess with the pathname and start splitting and what not. there must be a cleaner way like with react-router-dom

Comment: I updated my answer, though that is subjective to your folder structuring @gdsdasgga

Comment: oh i see, but i think i have to go with the first approach, since i have a different page for each component. anyway good to know that you can do it @keysl.